# Is there a performance / UX benefit of using react Suspense if no child suspends?

Tags: reactjs, react-concurrent

If I wrap a component in `Suspense` and its child does async work (or suspends for some other reason), then it gets rendered non-urgently when it's ready (based on [this](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/37) `Interacting with the page before all the components have hydrated` and [this](https://3perf.com/talks/react-concurrency/)).

This would be interesting to take advantage of for non-critical components. However they don't necessarily do any async work.

Would wrapping a component in this case still provide a benefit regarding performance / "perceived interactivity" by rendering it non-urgently?

The [react docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense#usage) make no mention of how Suspense will behave if none of its children suspend.